# How to use _nin in queries where the array is the result of the first query?

Tags: postgresql, graphql, hasura

have the following query

```
  bookings {
    timeslot_id
  }
  timeslots(where: {service_provider: {phone: {_eq: "+14155238886"}}, service: {name: {_like: "%mecanic%"}}, date_service: {_eq: ""2023-03-27""}, id: {_nin: [1,2]}}) {
    date_service
    id
    service_id
    service_provider_id
    start_time
    end_time
    service {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

So, how to use the result of the query bookings in the _nin filter in timeslots query?

Comment: You can't. Multiple queries submitted in a single request run independently. You either have to run the queries in separate requests or create a new query on the backend that performs the combined operation.

Comment: @MichelFloyd maybe there is a way to do that using only one query, as that goal here is to get the free time slots, but I don't know how

Comment: for reference https://hasura.io/docs/latest/schema/postgres/custom-functions/#supported-sql-functions

Comment: You need to figure out how to create a specific query in Hasura. (an ANTI-JOIN in your case)

Comment: It seems not possible

Comment: I'm sure there's a way, just need an experienced Hasura user to answer. I use knex.js myself.